# PowerBi - Getting 404 but works in Postman

Tags: json, powerbi, powerquery

I have some issues with Powerbi which is driving me insane.

Essentially, I have an API endpoint which accepts a JSON body:

> {key1:"value1",key2:"value2"}

It is a GET request on an endpoint: https://website.com/api/v1/endpoint

When making the GET request in Postman, everything works fine, and it outputs the response with HTTP 200 OK. In PowerBi (blank query) however, it is returning a 404. I did a console.log on the endpoint, it outputs with Postman, but doesn't output when the same request is made from PowerBi (making me believe its not even reaching the URL).

The Postman body looks like this:

[image: Postman Image]

In PowerBi, I am doing this:

```m
= let url = "https://website.com/api/v1/endpoint",
    body = "{""key1"": ""value1"",""key2"": ""value2""}",
    header = [#"Content-Type"= "application/json"],
    response = Web.Contents(url, [Content=Text.ToBinary(body),Headers = header]), 
    Source = Json.Document(response)

in
    Source
```

I am getting this as a response:

[image: PowerBi Image]

What is strange, is if I changed the PowerBi `Text.ToBinary(body)` to `Json.FromValue(body)`, it does reach the endpoint and I can see in the `console.log` output, the following:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

PowerBi also returns this as an error (note this time it is a 400 and not a 404):

[image: PowerBi 400 error]

Any help would be massively appreciated!

The response from the API would return a JSON object which I would then parse into PowerBi as a dataset.

Comment: When you send `content` in the request, then Power BI will do a `POST` vs `GET`. Is your API also listening to `POST`?

Comment: @SamNseir - The API is only listening to a GET